# Auto refresh Jqgrid cell

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I want to auto refresh a cell in jqgrid for each row without loading the grid each time.Can anybody tell me the code.

Answer (score -1):

look like you have not reading the manual of jqgrid, here some implementations of that

```
function refreshGrid() {
    var grid = $("#div");
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
    t = setTimeout("refreshGrid()", 10000);
}

$(function(){
refreshGrid();
});
```